# Software to massively change file names?

Tags: file-management

I'm looking for a software which allows me to massively change file names contained in a folder with several subfolders, giving them a pattern (for example, change all of them to consecutive numbers) Any recommendations?

Comment: What OS? Could be easy to do with a few lines of bash shell script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using an older version of [ReNamer from den4b](http://www.den4b.com/products/renamer) for many years. I see the new version also includes a file folder capability.

[image: Renamer screenshot]

The free version has a limit of five rules, although your requirements would generate only one rule, the serialization option. I've found it quite easy to use, very powerful and flexible as your logic circuits allow.

Answer (score 2):

[Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) has a batch mode facility that can rename files. The program is intended for handing image files but its batch mode may also work on non-image files. It offers several patterns for the new file names including sequential numbering.